# Any reason not to keep ViewModels in a separate, xaml-not-allowed assembly?

Tags: mvvm-light

Just wondering if I am shooting myself in the foot if I put all my ViewModels into a separate assembly from the xaml of my silverlight application?  Do I lose any blendability?

It just seems more natural to me to have the ViewModels, which are (or should be) completely UI independent, in a separate assembly from the Xaml/views.

Do I lose anything in the area of blendability?

Im thinking it pretty much forces ease of unit testing, or am I missing something?

I found one post on this that agrees with my sentiment, but MVVMLights default project creation seems to put them together, so Im wondering if I am missing the point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary, but it can be nice to do if you are striving for architectural purity. While VM library reuse is not common (as LBugnion said), it is quite common to retool your UI (or create a new one), in which case it can be very convenient to have a UI only assembly.
This also makes things simple if you are doing what i've heard talked about but never seen praticed in real life: having an independent UX designer work on the UI while the rest of the developers do the real code behind the scenes.

Following this practice will become more tiresome though if you have a larger project and are using something like Prism to manage modules - not only will you have several modules, each of those modules will have separate assemblies for UI and viewmodels/models, so you end up with many assemblies which can be difficult to manage or navigate.

Answer (score 1):

So long as the libraries are included in the solution, you can reference the ViewModels and not lose Blendability".

Normally (as we use PRISM) we collect all business-domain specific information into one module, so it will include Views, ViewMOdels, Controllers etc, but having a separate ViewModel library (or libraries) is OK and you are using MVVM Light.

Comment: I like to have clean separation between layers/concerns, so as long as having a separate assembly for ViewModels from the XAML UI doesnt create a lot of extra administrivia (managing the "extra" assembly), Im all for it.  Not having the XAML in with the ViewModels encourages separation in my opinion.  In fact, I am a proponent of 3 assemblies on the client- the UI/Views/XAML, the ViewModels, and another assembly for the Model/Services.  FWIW, I see the model and data services (I believe in a restful network API using JSON) as the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

We do this often for larger applications. For small ones, it is typically not really needed. Separating the assemblies like this does not have a real technical advantage (you rarely reuse a VM library) so it's really about organization of work and structure. In terms of Blendability, you don't lose anything. Also, if you work with services, you'll need to have the interface definition in the VM library (or in a 3rd project).

Note that sometimes you get confusing build error messages. If the VM library doesn't compile, you may see errors about non-existing objects in the XAML, which are simply caused by the fact that the library is not built yet. Don't get confused.

Cheers
Laurent

Comment: Thank you Laurent for answering...  :-)  I agree for small projects it aint all that useful, but my reasoning for it is to "overly encourage" the separation.  ie, its more of a forced discipline activity than anything else.  Not doing it for any technical reason.
I worked on a project yesterday with VMs and UI in separate assys, and think the overhead is negligible.  In the end, I like it.
only issue I ran in to is what you raised: the error messages in that scenario are a little hard to follow, but rebuild and all is well.

Comment: I also like the idea of the dummy data being in with the XAML, at the designers whim, wheres the real service/model is separated.  Im still learning my way of what feels right, so havent decided whether the service is in with the VMs, or separate.  My current thinking is it belongs in with the VMs, but after using it for a month or so, I might change my mind.
In any case, great work with this framework.  Its light enough to be easy to learn, but still provide the most bang for the buck- you rock! :-)